# Matlab fit function to give only positive values

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I'm using Matlabs fit() function to create a fit for a data set of 21 elements using the smoothingspline method. I get a very good fit except for one region where the function goes negative. My data is never negative and is expected to always be positive. Is there a way to force MATLAB to give a fitted function that will only produce positive values?

Thanks

Comment: Please give us the example code that produces the behaviour.

Comment: can you provide images of what you see, it might be that you are just seeing some extra oscillation with goes negative in a particular region. Otherwise I do not believe that there is a way to force the interpolation to have certain value in a region without initially having points in that region.